# Jetson Nano Adafruit ServoKit Detector can not detect Jetson

Tags: python, pip, adafruit, nvidia-jetson-nano

Trying to get ServoKit working on a Jetson Nano

Have installed Adafruit and ServoKit libraries:

Adafruit-Blinka                  6.15.0
adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice 5.1.5
adafruit-circuitpython-motor     3.3.5
adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685   3.4.10
adafruit-circuitpython-register  1.9.16
adafruit-circuitpython-requests  2.0.1
adafruit-circuitpython-servokit  1.3.9
adafruit-circuitpython-typing    1.9.4
adafruit-io                      2.7.0
Adafruit-PlatformDetect          3.52.3
Adafruit-PureIO                  1.1.11

We continuously get the same error - the platform detect library always finds 7H71x0.
Reverting to a previous detector version makes it detect the Jetson Nano as a Pi Pico.

`Initializing Servos Traceback (most recent call last): File "evieMotor.py", line 17, in <module> i2c_bus0=(busio.I2C(board.SCL_1, board.SDA_1)) File "/home/totus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/busio.py", line 32, in __init__ self.init(scl, sda, frequency) File "/home/totus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/busio.py", line 108, in init from microcontroller.pin import i2cPorts File "/home/totus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/microcontroller/__init__.py", line 65, in <module> elif chip_id == ap_chip.JH71x0: AttributeError: module 'adafruit_platformdetect.constants.chips' has no attribute 'JH71x0' Exiting...  Cleaning up pins`

Tried reverting library: pip3 install Adafruit-PlatformDetect==2.15.0
https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/40192

Thankyou in advance